# NFC application on android

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to build one application on android using NFC . I am very fresh to it. can anyone help me how to start with it .. I mean can anyone guide me where I can get the details about it like its protocol or it working procedure or hardware/software requirement to develop a simple application on the android .

Thanks in advance

Datta

Comment: Possibly the best NFC guide I have ever seen (explains the android demo) - http://www.tappednfc.com/wp-content/uploads/TAPPED-NFCDeveloperGuide-Part1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Start on developer.android.com, here is a good place: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html

You can also look at the code/install the demo NFC app that comes with the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an [NDEF editor](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) you might be interested in. It will help you get to know the most commonly used payload format in NFC on Android.

There is also a working boilerplate and some helpful data-bindings at [another project](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) I wrote.

Have fun :-)